# How to edit the xorg.conf

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, x11, nvidia, xorg

I use Ubuntu 14.04 USB boot. When I installed CUDA7.0, a black screen appeared, but I can enter console mode.

Stuff I tried:

- edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it could not be edited.
- calling `vim` with `sudo`, `su`, `su -`

The results of `ls` are shown below:

```
#ls -ls 
--------------------------
-rw-r--r-- root root
--------------------------
```

I can't understand that. This file can't be edited by the root authority.

```
#lsof ｜grep xorg.conf
--------------------------
there is nothing.
--------------------------
```

Even in recovery mode, I was in the same situation.

Comment: gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf ...  found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69392/how-to-change-xorg-conf-file-with-permission